# NSPredicate with Core Data issue

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I have Orders objects in Core Data database. Each of them have date and field **flag** = 0 or 1 (1 means that this object was loaded from server with all other objects and has all proper fields and it will not be changed anymore, 0 means that object can be changed later and I need to reload it from server later). I need to load that data in UITableView with NSFetchedresultController sorted by date, but I need to load this data only until 0 (because after that I will show UIActivityIndicator in the bottom of the table to load other data from server). For example, I have data sorted by date :

**1
1
1
1
1**
0
0
0
1
1
1
1

I need to load only first five objects (marked by bold font). I don't know how to write NSPredicate properly. If I write "flag > 0" I will load other objects with flag = 1. Right now I only see the solution to load all the data and to use **for** cycle to form proper array. But may there is a better solution?

Comment: Why not show all the rows with an indicator or a refresh button on the ones with a zero flag (which hopefully is stored as a bool false)?

Comment: Because in this case when user loaded the information he will not know what rows are up-to-date and what rows are with old data (may be 1 month old). And it's against the design to show indicator on rows with not up-to-date information. It's better to show only up-to-date rows until old rows. And it's a rare situation when user will have "0" rows, and will stimulate user to load old rows by one request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this as two fetches: first, fetch with a predicate `flag == 0`, sorted by date, with a `fetchLimit = 1`.  Get the value of the `date` attribute for that object (say `firstDate`), and use it in the predicate for the main fetch underlying the FRC (eg. `"date > %@", firstDate`).  If you get 0 results for the first fetch, then there's no need for the predicate - all the objects must have `flag == 1`.

Comment: Yes, that will work, if I just fetch objects. But I need to use it with NSFetchedResultController, so I don't know how to implement this. Or you mean: at first I need to find object with flat = 0 (first object) and only after that I need to create NSFetchRequest for NSFetchedResultController? (if yes, it will work too, but I hope that there is a better solution. If nobody answers, I will mark you answer as correct)

Comment: @PaulGalavic Yes, that's what I was intending: a first fetch, which provides the date for the predicate for the FRC.  I agree it's not ideal - hopefully someone will have a neater solution.

Answer (score 0):

To get the top 5 objects with flag 1 sorted by date

- Filter with `NSPredicate`for the flag
- Set the `NSSortDescriptor` to sort by date
- Set the `fetchLimit` to 5.

Comment: I don't know that number of objects with flag 1 will be 5. May it will be 150 (I need to fetch all the objects until "0" flag). So it can be 150 objects with flag = 1, then 5 objects with flag = 0 , and then 100 objects with flag = 1, and I need only this 150 objects

Comment: Fair enough. This was not stated clearly in the question. I think pbasdf's answer is viable.